# Combine several pyod model into one scikit learn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I recently discovered pyod for outlier detection in python. Many outlier detection algorithms are implemented in pyod, and the package also comes with several combination function to combine the outputs, such as `pyod.models.combination.average()`.

I would like to implement the combination of several models within a scikit learn pipeline. Unfortunately functions such as `pyod.models.combination.average()` are not usable as is in scikit pipeline.

What is the cleaner way to do so ? I'm expecting something like (please not the the CompositeDetector does not exist):

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
      (
          "composite_detector",
          CompositeDetector(
              [
                  IForest(),
                  CBLOF(),
              ],
              combination_method=average,
              contamination=contamination,
          )
      ),
  ])
```